# Activity indicator on table view in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, nsxmlparser

I have a table view containing parsed **NSXML** objects.

I want to implement an `activityIndicator` in this `tableview`, such that when data loading is complete the `activityIndicator` stops automatically.

How to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you having difficulty with any particular part? As it stands, this is quite a broad question.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are not familiar with `NSXmlParser`.

You should start `activity` in this method:

```
– parserDidStartDocument:
```

Then you can stop `activity` after the pasring stops in this delegate method:

```
– parserDidEndDocument:
```

You can refer to this apple doc for more information about `NSXMLParser` delegate.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I was tried that way.it not worked

Comment: Edited- `parserDidEndDocument` method calls?

Answer (score 1):

Use `int totalRows` and `Bool showSpinner` in your code,When call parsing method set `showSpinner=YES & totalRows=1` initially show spinner in table view and reload table view,after loading data set `totalRows count` and set `showSpinner=NO`, reload tableview

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return totalRows;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 NSString *identifier;
if(showSpinner)
{
 identifier=@"spinnerCell";
            UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
            if (cell==nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
                cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:spinner];
                spinner.tag = 123;
                CGRect _frame = [spinner frame];
                _frame.origin.y = 10;
                _frame.origin.x= (cellwidth/2)-(_frame.size.width/2);
                spinner.frame = _frame;
                [spinner startAnimating];
            }

            UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner=(UIActivityIndicatorView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];
            [spinner startAnimating];

}
else
{
identifier=@"dataCell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
            if (cell==nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
//add your custom cell or data
}
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an activity view inside cell, maybe next to title, you could use something like,

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[cell.imageView addSubview:activityView];
[activityView startAnimating];
```